# How can I draw a venn diagram using c3Js?

Tags: c3.js

Is there an easy way to draw a venn diagram in c3Js ? Currently I am using c3Js in my project and don't want to move to venn.js.

[image]

Comment: better to use [d3.js](https://d3js.org/). example plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/JayatiJaiswal/8tvz3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, at least I don't see anything about circular diagrms in the code.
I believe you could build your own d3 diagram or use venn.js like you wanted to.